# What is the expectation of the following random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots $ be an i.i.d. sequence of uniform random variables over $[0,1]$. Define
$$N= \min \{n \geq 1:X_1+\cdots+X_n>1\}$$
Find $P\{N>n\}$ and compute $E[N]$.

Comment: You seem to be using $n$ to mean two different things. Also, $N$ (under the assumptions and conditions given) is not well-defined. Please make certain that you've correctly copied everything down. Also, please share your thoughts and efforts on the problem so far, as it will help us tailor our answers to your needs.

Comment: I think something like this is meant:We have a sequence $X_1,X_2,...,X_i,X_{i+1},...$, now $N$ is the least indice such that $X_1+X_2+...+X_N$ exceeds one. Depending on the values of $X_i$s $N$ can be be different each time.

Comment: The question was copied correctly as stated. I guess the author has an error. I changed it to reflect what appears to be the correct statement. Right now I'm thinking the sum of iid uniform r.v. is a uniform r.v. but I'm stuck there.

Comment: A sum of iid uniform r.v. is not a uniform r.v. anymore, the distribution is giving by [the Irwin-Hall formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution).

Comment: Unfortunately, $N$ is still not well-defined. It is possible (though of probability $0$) that $X_n=0$ for all $n,$ and no matter how many $0$s we add up, the sum will not exceed $1$.

Comment: @CameronBuie This was an old qual question. I have located where it came from, a book called One Thousand Exercises in Probability. The way the problem is stated above is the same as in the book. Perhaps you should email the author about an errata:).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/214399/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/111314/321264.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1683558/321264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S_n=X_1+...+X_n \\
P(S_n \leq t),t<n=\text{The volume between the axises and the hyperplane X_1+X_2+...+X_n=t which is } \frac{t^n}{n!} \\ P(S_n \leq t)=\frac{t^n}{n!},t<n\\ f_{S_n}(t)=\frac{t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!},t<n \\ P(N=n)=\int\limits_0^1f_{S_{n-1}}(t)P(X_n>1-t)dt=\int\limits_0^1\frac{t^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}t dt=\frac{1}{n(n-2)!},n\geq2$

Comment: I lost you at $P(N=n)$. I wanted $P(N>n)$. I also fail to see how you incorporated that fact that $N$ is defined in terms of a minimum

Comment: $P(N=n) = P(S_{n-1}<1 \land S_{n}>1)$ this means that $\int\limits_{0}^{1}f(S_{n-1}=t \land X_n>1-t)dt$

Comment: I am new to the stochastic processes, it would be good to check the answer with the book. Good luck.

Comment: I just found a copy of the solution manual. It's fine.

Answer (score 3):

Supplement to the allready accepted answer of hhsaffar:

$P\left[N>n\right]=P\left[S_{n}\leq1\right]=\frac{1}{n!}$ and $E\left[N\right]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P\left\{ N\geq n\right\} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P\left\{ N>n\right\} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=e$