# Show that $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(S_n \geq 1) \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_ {\alpha}^{+\infty}e^{- t^2/2}dt$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let :

- $\forall n \geq 1, \quad S_n= \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k \quad$   where $(X_k)_k$ are independent $U[0,1]$
- $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$
- $T = \inf\{k \geq  n, S_n > 1\}$
- We want to show that :
  $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(S_n \geq 1) \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_ {\alpha}^{+\infty}e^{- \frac{t^2}{2}}dt$
  and deduce **from this** inequality the distribution of $T$ . The distribution of $T$ can be found with other methods like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2026999/expected-value-of-inf-nx-1-x-n-ge1-for-x-n-i-i-d-uniform-on?noredirect=1&lq=1).

---

My attempt :

1. For $ 0 \leq x \leq 1$,  we compute $P(S_n \leq x)=\frac{x^n}{ n!}$

$
\begin{align*}
\sigma_n &:= \int_{ [0,1]^n}    \mathbb{1}_{ \sum_{k=1}^n x_i <1 } \quad dx_1 \dots d{x_n} \\
 &=\int_{ [0,1]}     \int_{ [0,1]^{n-1}}   \mathbb{1}_{ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x_i <1-x_n }  \quad dx_1 \cdots d{x_{n-1}} dx_n \\
&= \int_{ [0,1]}     \int_{ [0,1]^{n-1}}   \mathbb{1}_{ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x_i <1-x_n }  \quad dx_1 \cdots d{x_{n-1}} dx_n \\
&=  \int_{ [0,1]}  (1-x_n)^{n-1}  \int_{ [0,1]^{n-1}}   \mathbb{1}_{ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x_i <1 }  \quad dx_1 \cdots d{x_{n-1}} dx_n \\
&= \sigma_{n-1} \int_{ [0,1]}  (1-x_n)^{n-1}  dx_n  \sigma_{n-1} \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sigma_{n-1} \\
&= \frac{1}{n!} \\
\end{align*}
$

$ 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}( \mathbb{1}_{ \sum_{k=1}^n X_i} <x) 
&= \int_{ [0,1]^n}    \mathbb{1}_{ \sum_{k=1}^n x_i <x } \quad dx_1 \cdots d{x_n} \\                   
&= x^n   \int_{ [0,1]^n}    \mathbb{1}_{ \sum_{k=1}^n x_i <1 } \quad dx_1 \cdots d{x_n} \\  
&= \frac{x^n}{ n!}  (\star)  \\
\end{align*}
$

2. Distribution of $T$

$
\begin{align*}
 \{S_n \leq 1 \} &= \{ T \geq n+1 \} \\
P(T=n) &= P(T\geq n) - P(T \geq n+1 ) \\
P(T=n) &= \frac{1}{n!} - \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \\
\end{align*}
$

3. There is an equality quite close that can be found by integration by parts :
   $$
   \int_{x}^{+\infty} e^{-t} \frac{t^n}{n!} dt
    = \sum_{k=0}^{n} e^{-x} \frac{x^k}{k!}
   $$