# Expected number of terms needed to get a sum greater than $T$, for i.i.d. random variables uniformly distributed in $(0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-distribution, expected-value

Suppose we have $T>0$, and $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a collection of i.i.d. random variables that are uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Define the random variable:
$$
N := \max \left\{ n \in \mathbb N_0 : S_n \leq T \right\}
$$
where $S_n := X_1 + \cdots X_n$. I want to compute $\mathbb E[N]$.

**What I've done:** I know $\mathbb E[N] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k\mathbb P[N=k]$, so the problem amounts to computing $\mathbb P[N = k]$. Assume $0 < T \leq 1$ (I think the problem gets complicated for $T > 1$, and I want to figure out the easy case first). We see that 
$$
\{N = k\} = \{S_k \leq T < S_{k+1}\},
$$
so the probability can be expressed in the iterated integral
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P[N=k] &= \int_0^1\cdots \int_0^1 \mathbb 1_{\{S_k \leq T\}}\mathbb 1_{\{T < S_{k+1}\}} \, dx_{k+1} \cdots dx_1 \\
&= \int_0^T \int_0^{T-S_1} \cdots \int_0^{T-S_k} \int_{T-S_k}^1 dx_{k+1} \,dx_k \cdots dx_2 \, dx_1.
\end{align*}
I was able to show by induction that this integral evaluates to 
$$
\mathbb P[N=k] = \frac{(-1)^k (1-T)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!} + \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{(-1)^{i-1}T^{k-i}}{i!(k-i+1)!}
$$
but this solution for the probability is a serious mess, and applying $\mathbb E[N] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k\mathbb P[N=k]$ doesn't seem to lead to anything nice.

**My question.** Is there anything standard that this sum converges to? Or anything similar? Something binomial, perhaps? Alternatively, is there an easier way to compute $\mathbb E[N]$? I saw on some posts that 
$$
\mathbb E[N] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb P[N > k]
$$
and these probabilities are much easier to compute and work out much more cleanly, but it's not clear to me why this is true.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/214399/321264.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$S_n$ follows the [Irwin–Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution). Therefore,

$$
\mathsf{P}(N> n)=\mathsf{P}(S_{n+1}\le T)=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor T\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n+1}{k}(T-k)^{n+1}
$$
and
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}N &=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor T\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(T-k)^n \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor T\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{n\ge 1\vee k}\frac{(T-k)^n}{(n-k)!} \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor T\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}(T-k)^ke^{T-k}-1.
\end{align}

In particular, for $T\in [0,1]$, $\mathsf{E}N=e^T-1$.

Comment: Nevermind......

Answer (score 3):

> Alternatively, is there an easier way to compute $\mathbb E[N]$?

Indeed, there is. For every nonnegative $t$, consider 
$N_t=\inf\{ n : S_n>t\}$ then your $N$ is $N_T-1$ hence it suffices to compute every $E(N_t)$. Conditioning on $X_1$, one sees that, for $t<1$, $$E(N_t)=1+\int_0^tE(N_{t-s})ds=1+\int_0^tE(N_s)ds$$ while, for $t>1$, $$E(N_t)=1+\int_0^1E(N_{t-s})ds=1+\int_{t-1}^tE(N_s)ds$$ Thus, the function $n(t)=E(N_t)$ solves the differential equation $$n'(t)=n(t)$$ on $(0,1)$, and the delayed differential equation $$n'(t)=n(t)-n(t-1)$$ on $t>1$, with the initial condition $n(0)=1$. Alternatively, $m(t)=e^{-t}n(t)$ solves the differential equation $$m'(t)=0$$ on $(0,1)$, and the delayed differential equation $$m'(t)=-e^{-t}n(t-1)=-e^{-1}m(t-1)$$ on $t>1$, with the initial condition $m(0)=1$.

Thus, $m(t)=1$ on $(0,1)$, $m(t)=1-e^{-1}(t-1)$ on $(1,2)$, and one can deduce recursively similar formulas for $m(t)$, hence for $n(t)$, on each interval $(k,k+1)$ with $k$ a natural integer. In the end, on $(k,k+1)$, $m(t)$ is a polynomial of degree $k$, and $n(t)=e^tm(t)$.  The result is related to the [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution).

The case of the  interval $(0,1)$ is especially pleasing since $m(t)=1$ on $(0,1)$ hence one gets simply $$E(N_t)=e^t$$ and, in particular, the a priori surprising value $$E(N_1)=e$$

Comment: @d.k.o. Thanks, corrected.

Comment: @Song Indeed, asymptotics when $t\to\infty$ are much easier than exat values for some fixed $t$ (but the correct statement is that $E(N_t)-(t/\mu)\to c$ when $t\to\infty$, for some explicit $c$ depending on $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ which is probably explained on the WP page).

Comment: I'm not seeing yet why $E(N_t) = 1+\int_0^t E(N_{t-s}) ds$. What do you mean by "conditioning on $X_1$?"

Comment: Use the fact that, for every $s$ in $(0,t)$, on $\{X_1=s\}$, $N_t=1+N'_{t-s}$ where $N'_{t-s}\stackrel{d}=N_{t-s}$.

Answer (score 2):

The simpler version in the post you mentioned is based on the fact that the mean of all non-negative integer 
$\mathbb{E}[N]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}Np(N=k)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}Pr\{N\geq i\}$.(Refer to this question: [Find the Mean for Non-Negative Integer-Valued Random Variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843845/find-the-mean-for-non-negative-integer-valued-random-variable) for the proof)

Take the simple case where $X_i\sim U(0,1)$ and $T\in [0,1]$ as an example: By induction, $Pr\{N\geq n+1\}=\frac{t^n}{n!}$ can be proved, so 
$$
\mathbb{E}(N)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty Pr\{N\geq i\}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=e^t
$$