# Let $X_i$ be iid with uniform distribution on $(0,100)$. Find expected number of $n$ random variables s.t $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \geq 1000$

Tags: probability, random-variables, solution-verification, expected-value

Let $X_i$ be iid with continuous uniform distribution on $(0,100)$. Find expected number of $N$

Where $$N = \min \{ n : \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \geq 1000  \}$$

My thoughts:

$E[\sum X_i] = \sum E[X_i]$, and each $E[X_i] = 50$. So it would take $20$ of $E[X_i]$ to reach $1000$. It seems rather straighfoward. But is this rigorious? Is there a "trap" I missed?

Comment: Is the uniform distribution continuous?

Comment: Suppose, instead of $1000$, $N$ was the expected number of trials needed to  get  $≥50$ .  Your logic would tell us that the answer was $1$, but this is clearly false (there is a $\frac 12$ probability that it will take at least $2$).

Comment: @d.k.o. yes it is

Comment: @lulu indeed... what would be the right solution to this problem

Comment: @StubbornAtom thanks!!!

Comment: Sorry that answer doesn't deal with the case here. See instead the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X_i/100 \sim U[0,1]$,
$$
\mathsf{E}N=\sum_{k=0}^{10}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}(10-k)^ke^{10-k}\approx 20.667.
$$
(See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3022309/expected-number-of-terms-needed-to-get-a-sum-greater-than-t-for-i-i-d-random) question.)