# How to prove this conclusion of a uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

$X_1,X_2,$.....are i.i.d standard uniform U(0,1),let
$$N:=\min\{n \ge2 | X_n>X_{n-1}\}$$
$$T=\min\{n \ge 1 | X_1+...+X_n>1\}$$

We have conclusions that:

1. $\mathbb{E}[N]=e$
2. $\mathbb{E}[T]=e$

Conclusion 1 is easy to prove, but how about 2?

Comment: What is the relationship between $T$ and $e$?

Comment: Sorry， E[T]=e，I made a clerical error

Comment: Is there something missing in your definition of $N$ that would make it a number rather than a set of numbers?

Comment: I re-edit the problem, clearer now

Comment: N is not a set, it is a random variable.

Comment: also, the T is a random variable

Comment: Is $N$ the least $n$ for which $X_n>X_{n-1}$?

Comment: Yes, and T is the smallest n for which $\sum_{n=1}^{n}X_n>1$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/214399/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/111314/321264

Answer (score 2):

Here is the proof of conclusion 1:
$$\mathbb{P}(N>n)=\mathbb{P}(X_1>X_2>...>X_n)=\frac{1}{n!}$$
$$\mathbb{E}[N]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(N>n)=e$$

Comment: I use python to get conclusion 2, but I don't have specific proof, so I'm looking for the proof of conclusion 2.