# sum of uniform $[0,1]$

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-distribution

Let :

- $(X_i)_{i \geq 1}$ uniform on $[0,1]$ independants
- $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$
- $H_n$ is the cumulative fonction of $S_n$

1. I prove that $H_{n+1}(x)= \int_{x-1}^{x} H_n(t) dt$ for all $x$
2. I want to deduce from 1. $H_n(x)$ for $0\leq x \leq 1$

The result is given on several topics, like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214399/summing-0-1-uniform-random-variables-up-to-1?noredirect=1&lq=1). How can I deduce it from 1. ?

---

My attempt :

For all $x$ :

$ 
\begin{align*}
H_{n+1} (x)
&= P(S_{n+1} \leq x) \\
&= P(S_{n} + X_{n+1} \leq x) \\
& = \int_{0}^{1} P( S_n +u \leq x) du \\
&=  \int_{0}^{1} P( S_n  \leq x-u) du \\
&= \int_{x-1}^{x} P( S_n  \leq s) ds \\
&=\int_{x-1}^{x} H_n(s) ds \\
\end{align*}
$

$ 
\begin{align*}
H_{n+1} (x)&=\int_{0}^{x} H_n(s) ds \\
H_2(x) &= \frac{x^2}{2} \\
H'_{n+1}&=H_n \\
d^k H_{n+1}&=H_{n+1-k} \\
\forall n \quad H(0)&=0 \\
\end{align*}
 $

$$P(S_n \leq x) = \frac{ x^n}{ n!} $$

Comment: Use a proof by induction.

Comment: Thanks, I may have found the answer.