# Distribution of a smallest index

Tags: probability, order-statistics

We have the i.i.d. sequence $\{X\}$ where  $X_i \sim U[0,1]$. Define the number 
$N = \text{min}\{n\geq1: X_1 + \ldots +X_n >x\} $ for $x \in (0,1)$. What is Pr$\{N > n\}$?

My attempt at a solution:
Pr$\{N > n\} =$ Pr$\{X_1 + \ldots + X_n \leq x\} = \int_{A_x}\mathrm{d}x_1 \ldots \mathrm{d}x_n$, where $A_x = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_n):0\leq \sum^n_{i=1} x_i \leq x\}$

Correct answer is: Pr$\{N > n\} = \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Need help with:

- compute integral
- Is Pr$\{N > n\} =$ Pr$\{X_1 + \ldots + X_n \leq x\}$ even correct?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choose a random number between $0$ and $1$ and record its value. Keep doing it until the sum of the numbers exceeds $1$. How many tries do we need?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111314/choose-a-random-number-between-0-and-1-and-record-its-value-keep-doing-it-u)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1128396/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1683558/321264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hint for a solution: Look at the case that $N > 2$. Then:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{P}(N > 2) & = \mathbf{P}(X_1 \leq x, X_2 < x - X_1) \\ 
& = \int_0^{x-x_1}\int_0^xdx_1dx_2 \\ 
& = \int_0^x(x-x_1)dx_1 \\ 
& = \frac{x^2}{2}. \\
\end{align}$$

You can then show the general case by induction. And yes, your equality is correct.

Edit: I removed an introductory remark which made no sense for only positive random variables. Also corrected some obvious typos.

Comment: Thank you, a very good answer. Only thing that could be said is that one could simply verify the case that N>1.