# An interesting stopping time problem using PGF's

Tags: probability, number-theory, generating-functions, stopping-times

This is a question I thought of the other day:

> Suppose $U_1, U_2, U_3, \cdots \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \text{Uniform}(0, 1)$ and let $N = \min\{n: \sum_{i=1}^{n}U_i \ge 1\}$. Compute $\mathbb{P}(N \in 2\mathbb{Z})$ (i.e. probability $N$ is even). How about $\mathbb{P}(N \in 3 \mathbb{Z})$? In general, $\mathbb{P}(N \in k\mathbb{Z})$. Similarly, what is $\mathbb{E}[N|N \in k\mathbb{Z}]$?

I'll post the answer below, but challenge yourself before looking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are going to need a few results to answer this question.

**Definition** The probability generating function (PGF) of a random variable $X$ with support $\mathbb{N}_0 = \{0, 1, 2, \cdots\}$ is defined as $g_X(s) = \mathbb{E}[s^X]$.

**Fact 1** By definition,
\begin{align*}
g_X(s) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X = k)s^k
\end{align*}

**Fact 2** We have
\begin{align*}
H_X(s) \overset{\text{def}}{=}\frac{1-g_X(s)}{1-s} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\mathbb{P}(X > k)s^k 
\end{align*}

**Fact 3** We have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X \in k\mathbb{Z}) = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}g_X(\omega_{k,j})
\end{align*}
where $\omega_{k,j} = \exp\left(\frac{2j\pi \mathbf{i}}{k}\right)$ are the $k$th roots of unity, with $\mathbf{i}$ being the imaginary unit.

Now we can attack this problem. First, note that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(N > n) = \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k < 1\right) = \frac{1}{n!}
\end{align*}
Since the probability corresponds to finding the volume of an $n$-dimensional right tetrahedron with leg side lengths 1. So we have
\begin{align*}
H_N(s) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(N > k)s^k = e^s
\end{align*}
And therefore $g_N(s) = 1 - (1-s)H_N(s) = 1 - (1-s)e^s$. We can now see that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(N \in 2\mathbb{Z}) &= \frac{1 + g_N(-1)}{2} = 1 - e^{-1} \approx 0.6321 \\
\mathbb{P}(N \in 3\mathbb{Z}) &= \frac{1 + g_N(\exp(2\pi \mathbf{i}/3)) + g_N(\exp(4\pi \mathbf{i}/3))}{3} = 1 - \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{3e}} - \frac{\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{e}} \approx 0.3403 \\
\mathbb{P}(N \in 4\mathbb{Z}) &= \frac{1 + g_N(\mathbf{i}) + g_N(-1) + g_N(-\mathbf{i})}{4} = 1 - \frac{1}{2}e^{-1} - \frac{\sin(1)}{2} - \frac{\cos(1)}{2}\approx 0.1252 \\
&\vdots
\end{align*}
and so on. For expected values, we use the formula that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[N|N \in k\mathbb{Z}] = \frac{\sum_{n \in k\mathbb{N}_0}n \mathbb{P}(N = n)}{\mathbb{P}(N \in k\mathbb{Z})}
\end{align*}
Define
\begin{align*}
L_N(s) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty n \mathbb{P}(N = n) s^n
\end{align*}
Note that $L_N(s) = s \frac{d}{ds} g_N(s) = s^2 e^s$ and
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \in k\mathbb{N}_0}n \mathbb{P}(N = n) = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} L_N(\omega_{k,j})
\end{align*}
Plugging in these values, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[N|N \in 2\mathbb{Z}] &= \frac{\frac{1}{2}(e^1 + e^{-1})}{1 - e^{-1}} \approx 2.44 \\
\mathbb{E}[N|N \in 3\mathbb{Z}] &= \frac{\frac{e}{3} + \frac{2 \sin(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - \frac{\pi}{6})}{3\sqrt{e}}}{1  - \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{3e}} - \frac{\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{e}}} \approx 3.06 \\
\mathbb{E}[N|N \in 4\mathbb{Z}] &= \frac{\frac{1}{4}e^{-1} + \frac{1}{4}e - \frac{\cos(1)}{2}}{1 - \frac{1}{2}e^{-1} - \frac{\sin(1)}{2} - \frac{\cos(1)}{2}} \approx 4.0055
\end{align*}
and so on.

**Challenge** Do the same thing to compute $\text{Var}(N|N \in k \mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more general solution for any stopping point $0 <c \le 1$ that nests the special case of $c = 1$ posed in the question.

As set out at [Random sums of iid Uniform random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128396/random-sums-of-iid-uniform-random-variables/), by simple geometric construction, the cdf of the number $N$ of draws required to exceed $c$, for $0<c \le 1$, is:  $P(N \leq n) = 1 - \large \frac{c^n}{n!}$.

Then the pmf of $N$ is $f(n)$:

[image]

The probability that $N$ is even  (using *Mathematica/mathStatica* here to quickly do the nitty gritties), is:

[image]

Then, the pmf of $N$, conditional on $N$ being even is:

[image]

Now that we have the conditional pmf, it is straightforwards to derive any conditional moments. The mean of $N$, conditional on $N$ being even is:

[image]

In the special case when $c = 1$ (as considered by the OP), the solution simplifies to: $\frac{1+e^2}{2 (e-1)} \approx 2.44112$

Similarly, $\text{Var}(N)$ conditional on $N$ being even is simply:

[image]

The same approach works just as well for multiples of 3 or 4 etc