# What is the expected value of the number of randomly chosen real numbers between $0$ and $1$ needed to reach a sum of $1$?

Tags: calculus, probability, expectation

My friend told me that the answer to this question was $e$, which intrigued me, but he refused to tell me why.

My initial intuition was completely wrong. I thought that since the expected value of any one of these numbers (uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$) was $1/2$, the expected number of them you'd need to get a sum of $1$ would be two. I realized this was rather stupid.

---

This is my attempt at calculating the expected value term-by term. Let $N$ be the number of numbers between $0$ and $1$ necessary for their sum to exceed $1$, and let $P(N=k)$ be the probability that it takes $k$ such numbers. Then the expected value of $N$ is $$E(N) = P(N=2) \cdot 2 + P(N=3) \cdot 3 + P(N=4) \cdot 4 + \cdots$$

I then calculated the first term:

$$P(N=2) \cdot 2 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 = 1$$

Unfortunately, the second and higher terms aren't as easy ...

Comment: First of all, it can't be $2$, because the probability that you reach $1$ in one choice is $0$, so $2$ is minimum value for the number, so the average value of the number would have to be more than $2$ unless it was almost always $2$...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111314/choose-a-random-number-between-0-and-1-and-record-its-value-and-keep-doing-it-u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier to write this as $P(N>0)+P(N>1) + P(N>2)\dots$.

Then you need to see that $P(N>k)=\frac{1}{k!}$, which is essentially a geometric argument - the ($k$-dimensional) volume of $\{(x_1,\dots,x_k)\in[0,1]^k:x_1+\dots+x_k<1\}$ is $\frac{1}{k!}$.

For the first line:

$$\begin{align}P(N>0) &= P(N=1)+&P(N=2)+&P(N=3)+\dots\\
P(N>1)&=&P(N=2)+&P(N=3)+\dots\\
P(N>2)&=&&P(N=3)+\dots
\end{align}$$

Add them up and you get $\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(N>k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty kP(N=k) = E(N)$.

Comment: A justification of [the volume statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Volume), for the curious

Comment: By $N$, do you mean they same $N$ as I do in the question? It doesn't seem to make sense with the greater-thans...

Comment: Same $N$ as your question. You'll have to be more specific - I've definitely left out steps... @ZubinMukerjee

Comment: I guess I don't see how you got the very first line as the expected value.

Comment: I've added a note on the first line, above.