# Expected number of picks from normal distribution such that the sum exceeds ? Does the value converge?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, expected-value, laplace-transform, stopping-times

I have found the [similar question for Uniform Distribution i.e, U(0,1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111314/choose-a-random-number-between-0-and-1-and-record-its-value-keep-doing-it-u) but not for Normal distribution,

So basically the problem is, using a standard normal distribution i.e., ∼(,$^2$)
random number generator, keep generating and summing until the sum is greater than .

How to find the expected number of moves you will take. I am not even sure the value is defined.

I was modelling the equation like here - [Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4752182/1291023), and now the equation also has Normal distribution term in the right hand side while picking a number, this converts it to a form where it appears, convolution theorem might be used, tho I am not able to proceed ahead or gain any useful breakthrough.

Welcome to any other methods as well

Comment: Standard normal distributied random numbers with a mean of $0$ will never sum up to $r$, me think.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\mu$ and $r$ are positive.  Let $Y_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ be i.i.d., and let $X_r$ be the minimum number of these variables needed to sum to at least $r$.  Then you have
$$
E[X_r]=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P[X_r > k] = 1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P[Y_1+\ldots+Y_k < r].
$$
Since $Y_1+\ldots+Y_k \sim N(k\mu, k\sigma^2)$, this reduces to
$$
E[X_r]=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Phi\left(\frac{r-k\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{k}}\right),
$$
where $\Phi$ is the c.d.f. of the standard normal distribution.  This sum converges; the terms (once $k\mu \gg r$) decay exponentially with $k$.

Comment: How did you write the Probability summation to CDF summation, why the division with sigma root k, also how do we proceed after this, I am not very sure how to proceed with sum where lot of CDF of normal is present

Comment: $P[Y_1+\ldots+Y_k < r]$ is equal to $P[(Y_1 - \mu) + \ldots +(Y_k-\mu) < r - k\mu]$, which in turn is equal to $P[(Y_1 - \mu)/(\sigma\sqrt{k})+ \ldots + (Y_k-\mu)/(\sigma\sqrt{k}) < (r-k\mu)/(\sigma\sqrt{k})]$.  But $(Y_i - \mu)/(\sigma\sqrt{k})$ is $\sim N(0, 1/k)$, and so the sum of $k$ such variables is $\sim N(0, 1)$.