# First passage time for the sum of i.i.d uniform distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $U_1,...,U_n$ are i.i.d uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.
Define
$$N=\min\{n\geq 0:\sum_{i=1}^{n}U_i>\frac{1}{2}\}$$

Compute $EN$

Comment: You know something about martingales and stopping times?

Comment: @DominikKutek Yes, I know, but this doesn't help here.

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/111314/601852

Comment: you're right, martingale theory only gives us bound $\mathbb E[N] \in [1,3]$ and can help us find $\mathbb E[ \sum_{i=1}^N U_i]$ if we already have $\mathbb E[N]$. Sorry, I was wrong, but as it seems in the shared question, you can find distribution of $N$ by just integrating scaled symplex

Comment: Thank you @DominikKutek. This helps me.