# How many random real numbers are needed for sum to exceed $1$, if each number is uniformly distributed from $0$ to constant $\times$ previous number?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, random-variables, expected-value

Let $u_1$ be a random real number uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1$.

Let $u_k$ be a random real number uniformly distributed between $0$ and $a\times{u_{k-1}}$, for $k>1$ and fixed positive real number $a$.

> What is the expected minimum value of $n$ such that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n u_k>1$, in terms of $a$?

(In other words, on average how many $u$'s are needed for their sum to exceed $1$?)

I did simulations using Excel. For small values of $a$ (e.g. $4$), sometimes the sequence of $u$'s gets "stuck" around very low values, so that many $u$'s are required for their sum to exceed $1$. I suspect the expectation is infinity for low values of $a$, and possibly for all values of $a$.

This is a variation of a simpler question: On average, how many uniformly random real number between $0$ and $1$ are needed for their sum to exceed $1$? The [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111314/choose-a-random-number-between-0-and-1-and-record-its-value-keep-doing-it-u) to that question is $e$. I tried to apply similar methods to my question, to no avail.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: Did you notice any change of behaviour around $a=\mathrm e$? You're adding $\log a$ plus the logarithm of a variable uniformly drawn from $[0,1]$ in each iteration; the expectation of that logarithm is $-1$; so I'd expect the expected time to be finite for $\log a\gt1$ and infinite for $\log a\lt1$.

Comment: @joriki I didn't notice any sudden change of behavior around $a=e$, but I just used Excel, which is rather crude.

Comment: It wouldn't be "sudden" in the sense of being obvious from short runs – but if your runs are long enough, the $u_k$ should diverge to $\infty$ for $a\gt\mathrm e$ and to $0$ for $a\lt\mathrm e$.

Comment: @joriki: I'm doing some long runs (100 million trials, using double-precision arithmetic) for various values of $a$. There does seem to be a phase change somewhere around $a=e$, but it's very hard to pin down, because even with $a$ as high as $2.74$ we find trials that end up with $u_k=0$ (and so they never halt). So I don't think numerical experiments can get very far.

Comment: @joriki "You're adding $log a$
 plus the logarithm of a variable uniformly drawn from $[0,1]$  in each iteration" Actually only $u_1$ is uniform in $[0,1]$, the others are uniform in $[0, a u_{k-1}]$

Comment: @leonbloy: I'd implicitly transformed the problem to $u_k=x_{k-1}au_{k-1}$, and thus $u_k=u_1\prod_{i\lt k}(ax_i)$ and $\log u_k=\log u_i+\sum_{i\lt k}\left(\log a+\log x_i\right)$, with the $x_i$ uniformly drawn from $[0,1]$.

Comment: The expectation diverges for $a<e$ and converges for $a>e$. The case $a=e$ is quite interesting, and I only have a naïve guess that the expectation is still finite in this case (which is contrary to the fact that the return time of a simple random walk has infinite expectation).

Comment: @SangchulLee I posted a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/441457/494920) about the case with $a=e$ on MO.

Comment: @SanchulLee Please could you explain why the expectation diverges for $a<e$ and converges for $a>e$. At first I thought I understood why, but now I don't. I editted my MO question to explain my thoughts about this. Thanks.

Comment: @SangchulLee I saw your answer at the MO question; thank you!

Comment: @Dan, No problem! Also, Now I am beginning to suspect that the expected number of terms when $a=e$ is infinite. I still have only half-baked ideas about this, but will definitely share some if I come up with more convincing arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_i$ be i.i.d. Uniform[0,1], and $S_n=X_1+aX_2+...+a^{n-1}X_n$.
Your question is: when $\mathbb{E}\tau<\infty$ where
$$
\tau=\min\{n: S_n\ge 1\}.
$$
**Claim**: if $0\le a<1$, then $S=\lim_n S_n<\infty$ with a positive probability; hence $\mathbb{E}\tau=\infty$.

**Proof**: let (non-random) $N$ be so large that $a^{N}+a^{N+1}+a^{N+2}+\dots=\frac{a^N}{1-a}<1/2$; such an $N$ exists since $a<1$. Now, with some *positive probability* $S_N<1/2$; and at the same time
$$
S-S_N=a^{N} X_{N+1}+a^{N+1} X_{N+2}+...\le a^{N}+a^{N+1}+a^{N+2}+\dots<1/2
$$
As a result, $S<1$.

Next, **for $a\ge 1$**,  $\mathbb{E}\tau<\infty$ as $S$ is clearly monotone in $a$ and we know the answer for $a=1$. In fact, one can compute $\mathbb{E}\tau$ in the same spirit as it is done for $a=1$: indeed,
$$
\mathbb{E}\tau=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(\tau>n)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(S_n<1)
$$
The collection of $(x_1,...,x_n)$ such that $x_1+ax_2+...+a^{n-1}x_n$, $x_i\ge 0$, is a stretched simplex (by $a^{k-1}$ at side $k=1,2,\dots,n$), hence its volume is
$$
\frac{1}{n!}\cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{a}  \cdot \frac{1}{a^2}
... \cdot \frac{1}{a^{n-1}}
$$
so
$$
\mathbb{E}\tau=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^{-n(n-1)/2}}{n!}
$$
[image]

Comment: I think we're talking about different questions. My question is to find 
$\mathbb{E}(\min\{n:X_1+aX_1X_2+a^2 X_1X_2X_3+\ldots+a^{n-1}X_1X_2X_3\cdots X_n>1\})$.

Comment: In this case, the answer is the following. $X_1....X_n=e^{n T_n}$ where $T_n=\frac{1}{n}(\ln X_1 +\dots+\ln X_n)$. By the strong law, $T_n\to \mathbb{E}\ln(X_1)=-1$ a.s. So the $n$th term of the sum behaves like $\gamma^n$ where $\gamma=a e^{-1}$. As a result, for $a<e$, with a positive probability the sum never exceeds $1$, while in the other case it reaches $1$ quite quickly. In the first case $\mathbb{E}\tau=\infty$ but it's $<\infty$ in the second case.