# Choose a random number btwn 0 and 1. Keep doing it until the sum of the numbers exceeds 1. Expected value of this sum?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

This is a modified version to a pretty common problem; here's that classic problem: [Choose a random number between $0$ and $1$ and record its value. Keep doing it until the sum of the numbers exceeds $1$. How many tries do we need?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111314/choose-a-random-number-between-0-and-1-and-record-its-value-keep-doing-it-u?noredirect=1&lq=1). That question has an answer of $e$.

My question is, once you reach a sum exceeding 1, what's the expected value of this sum? I saw somewhere the answer is $\frac{e}{2}$. That seems intuitive because the expected value of each number is $\frac{1}{2}$, but that doesn't seem very rigorous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is formalised by [Wald's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation#General_version). Apply it with $X_n$ equal to the $n$-th random number and $N=\inf\left\{n\in\mathbb N^*\mid\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\ge1\right\}$. Then
$$
\mathbb E\left[\sum_{k=1}^NX_k\right]=\mathbb E[N]\times\mathbb E[X_1]=\mathrm{e}\times\frac12.
$$

Comment: But doesn't $N$ have to be independent of the $X$'s to apply Wald's? And I feel like these are dependent; if you have a larger $X_1$ value, aren't you more likely to have a smaller $N$ (and vice versa)?

Comment: For the so-called [basic version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation#Basic_version) yes. For the general version you can see you just need $\{N\ge n\}$ to be independent of $X_n$. This is the case here because $\{N\ge n\}=\{N\le n-1\}^\complement$ depends on $(X_1,\cdots,X_{n-1})$, which is independent of $X_n$.

Comment: Thanks! For anyone wanting to learn more, [this link](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~pw/math100w13/hein.pdf) does a pretty good job of explaining Wald's.